# Why is this not being saved in public folder gives 404 error in Network?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Inside connection.js in backend, and 2nd code is inside post.jsx in front end.

```
router.post("/upload", (req, res) => {
      if (req.file === null) {
    return res.status(400).json({ msg: "No file uploaded" });
  }
  const file = req.files.file;
  file.mv(`../backend/public/${file.name}`, err => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return res.status(500).send(err);
    }
    res.json({ fileName: file.name, filePath: `/${file.name}` });
  });
});
```

This is indise my JSX file and this is all inside a form which when I save a photo everything is displayed inside console.log, that it the Path and the name, but it should be saved inside a public static folder as well.

```
const FileUpload = () => {
  const [file, setFile] = useState("");
  const [filename, setFilename] = useState("Choose File");
  const [uploadedFile, setUploadedFile] = useState({});

  const onChange = e => {
    setFile(e.target.files[0]);
    setFilename(e.target.files[0].name);
  };
    const onSubmit = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", file);

    try {
      const res = await axios.post("/upload", formData, {
        header: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
        }
      });
      const { fileName, filePath } = res.data;

      setUploadedFile({ fileName, filePath });
    } catch (err) {
      if (err.response.status === 500) {
        console.log("There was a problem with the server");
      } else {
        console.log(err.response.data.msg);
      }
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are saving array, than you access it via req.files other vise your file is in req.file . If you are saving an array so req.files, you must loop through it and then save to public what you need may be this is the issue